# How to automatically open private Youtube url on remote windows PC in VLC full screen?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, youtube, clipboard, vlc

Here is my workflow:

if sent email with Youtube link with subject "live stream" then IFTTT Dropbox create txt file with link on remote PC. NirCmd copy link from created txt file to clipboard.

```
nircmd.exe clipboard readfile "c:\Dropbox\Stream.txt"
```

Now I need to play Youtube URL from clipboard in VLC full screen with batch. I am trying:

```
@echo off 
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %clipboard%
```

But it's not working. Any help?

Comment: You may want to look at https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Answer (score 0):

> -f, --fullscreen : Start video in fullscreen mode (default disabled)

For more help on **[*vlc command-line*](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)**

This two examples showing you how to open video with the VLC application with ***fullscreen***

***Edwin Starr - War Live (2001)***

```
@echo off
Title Edwin Starr - War Live (2001)  
mode con:cols=40 lines=2
COLOR 1C
set Title=Edwin Starr - War Live (2001) 
set URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrZkHKANrNw
if exist %systemdrive%\Progra~2\Videolan\VLC (SET "vlc=%systemdrive%\Progra~2\Videolan\VLC\vlc") else (SET "vlc=%systemdrive%\Progra~1\Videolan\VLC\vlc")
Start /min "" %vlc% "%URL%" -f --meta-title="%Title%"
```

***The Hobbit 3 : The Battle of the Five Armies***

```
@echo off
Title The Hobbit 3 : The Battle of the Five Armies by Hackoo
mode con:cols=40 lines=2
COLOR 1C
set Title=The Hobbit 3 : The Battle of the Five Armies by Hackoo
set URL=http://urlz.fr/2XVB
if exist %systemdrive%\Progra~2\Videolan\VLC (SET "vlc=%systemdrive%\Progra~2\Videolan\VLC\vlc") else (SET "vlc=%systemdrive%\Progra~1\Videolan\VLC\vlc")
Start "" %vlc% "%URL%" --fullscreen --meta-title="%Title%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Is that amazing what VLC able to play txt file with link inside.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "C:\Dropbox\stream.txt"
```